# PHP post variable is not being rendered

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache

I have a PHP program that takes in a image name and loads the image and displays the name and the image on the page.

The variable in javascrip is written as

```
var latest_image_name = '<?=$post_img_name?>';
```

The PHP code is

```
<?php
        foreach($files_assoc_array_keys as $file_name){
            if($file_name==$post_img_name){
            ?>
            <label class="lbl_image_name active"><?=$file_name?></label>
            <?php
            }else{
            ?>
            <label class="lbl_image_name"><?=$file_name?></label>
            <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
```

the html output, is being rendered as

```
<div id="image_list_wrapper">
                    <label class="lbl_image_name"><?=$file_name?></label>
                    </div>
```

And as you can see it seems that PHP has not replaced the tag with the posted image name.

The code works on the original server that it was developed on, it does not work when i migrated it to another server, i have tried two other servers both Centos 6.4 with apache and PHP installed. I am not sure what the setup was for the original server that it as does work on.

the full code is seen below

```
<?php
header('Refresh: 5; URL=display.php');
print_r($_POST['post_img_name']);
$target_directory = "uploaded_images";

if(!file_exists($target_directory)){
    mkdir($target_directory);
}



if(isset($_POST['del_image'])) {
    $del_image_name = $_POST['del_img_name'];
    if(file_exists($target_directory."/".$del_image_name.".jpg")){
        unlink($target_directory."/".$del_image_name.".jpg");
    }
if(is_dir_empty($target_directory)){
        die("Last image delete. No images exist now.");
}
    $post_img_name = basename(get_latest_file_name($target_directory), '.jpg');

}else if(isset($_POST['post_img_name'])){
    $post_img_name=$_POST['post_img_name'];
    $post_img_temp_name = $_FILES['post_img_file']['tmp_name'];
}else{
    $post_img_name = basename(get_latest_file_name($target_directory), '.jpg');
}

$files_array = new DirectoryIterator($target_directory);
$total_number_of_files = iterator_count($files_array) - 2;
$files_assoc_array = array();


$already_exists = "false";
if($total_number_of_files != 0){
    foreach ($files_array as $file_info){
        $info = pathinfo( $file_info->getFilename() );
        $filename = $info['filename'];
        if ($filename==$post_img_name) {
            $already_exists = "true";
        }
    }
}

if(!isset($_POST['del_image']) && isset($_POST['post_img_name'])){
    $target_file = "$target_directory"."/".$post_img_name.".jpg";
    $source_file = $post_img_temp_name;



    if($already_exists == "true"){
        unlink($target_file);
    }
    move_uploaded_file($source_file, $target_file);
}



foreach ($files_array as $file_info){
    $info = pathinfo( $file_info->getFilename() );
    $filename = $info['filename'];
    if(!$file_info->isDot()){
        $files_assoc_array[$filename] =  $target_directory."/".$file_info->getFilename();
    }
}

$files_assoc_array_keys = array_keys($files_assoc_array);

function get_latest_file_name($target_directory){
    $files_array = new DirectoryIterator($target_directory);
    $total_number_of_files = iterator_count($files_array) - 2;
    $timestamps_array = array();

    if($total_number_of_files!=0){
        foreach($files_array as $file){
            if(!$file->isDot()){
                $timestamps_array[filemtime($target_directory."/".$file)] = $file->getFilename();
            }
        }
    }
    $max_timestamp = max(array_keys($timestamps_array));
    return $timestamps_array[$max_timestamp];

}
function is_dir_empty($dir) {
    if (!is_readable($dir))
        return NULL;
    $handle = opendir($dir);
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var files_array_text = '<?php echo implode(", ", $files_assoc_array)?>';
        var files_array_keys_text = '<?php echo implode(", ", $files_assoc_array_keys)?>';

        var files_array = files_array_text.split(", ");
        var files_array_keys = files_array_keys_text.split(", ");

        var files_assoc_array = createAssociativeArray(files_array_keys, files_array);

        var latest_image_name = '<?=$post_img_name?>';
        display_image(latest_image_name);


        $('.lbl_image_name').click(function(){
            $('#img_loading').show();
            $('#img_display').hide();

            var image_name = $(this).text();
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');

            display_image(image_name);
        });

        function createAssociativeArray(arr1, arr2) {
            var arr = {};
            for(var i = 0, ii = arr1.length; i<ii; i++) {
                arr[arr1[i]] = arr2[i];
            }
            return arr;
        }

        function display_image(image_name){
            var image_path = files_assoc_array[image_name];
            $('#img_display').attr('src', image_path);
            $('#img_display').load(image_path, function(){
                $('#img_loading').hide();
                $('#img_display').show();
            })

        }
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="image_list_wrapper">
            <?php
            foreach($files_assoc_array_keys as $file_name){
                if($file_name==$post_img_name){
                    ?>
                    <label class="lbl_image_name active"><?=$file_name?></label>
                    <?php
                }else{
                    ?>
                    <label class="lbl_image_name"><?=$file_name?></label>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <div id="image_display_wrapper">
            <div id="img_loading_wrapper">
                <img src="images/loading.gif" id="img_loading"/>
            </div>

            <img src="" id="img_display"/>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both">

        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="index.php">Go Back</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure the use of `<?= ... ?>` works on your server? try using `<?php .. ?>`

Answer (score 0):

As arbitter has pointed out my server did not support `<?= ... ?>` it worked after i changed to `<?php print $variable_name ?>`